# What does "dc" stand for in this Positive Bending Moment for Plastic resistance of a composite concrete slab formula?

Tags: structural-engineering, steel, concrete, composite

[image]

I'm designing a building with a composite slab with profile sheeting and steel structure, while trying to test the resistance of the composite slab in "composite phase" to bending moment I came across this formula to compute the intrinsic  "plastic moment resistance". What bugs me is that in this chapter, they give details about anything else and leave out "dc".
Anyone got a clear idea what about what is it?
Thanks!

Comment: To me it looks like someone meant hc.

Comment: I thought it was a typo for "dp" because of the lever arm for the moment, could also be "hc".

Comment: Try 'em both and see what result makes the most sense.